# Simple CSS3 animation makes scrolling choppy

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make a very simple animation with CSS3 on a webpage I'm building, all I want is to spin a png file with transparency. I got it to spin but the scrolling of the page now is choppy, do you have any tip on how to solve this?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hybam/SaNbb/1/

website (early stage of development): http://fractale.es/boilerplate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow: hidden` on the containing div. I'm not sure if understand the problem fully.

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain myself well, my English isn't that good. Let me try to say it this way, the problem I have is that when you scroll [here](http://fractale.es/boilerplate/) and the spinning image is on the screen, the scrolling isn't that smooth. Maybe I'm a little paranoid. Thanks for the tip on adding the `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Hmm... It seems to me that the css spin wouldn't cause the problem. Maybe you have some script or something that could be causing it. The scrolling seems fine to me though.